# Charged excitations and Vortices in abstract Abelian Lattice Gauge theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, lattice-gauge-theory

I have a question about heuristical interpretation of certain used terminology in the setting of abstract Abelian gauge theories as used in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1781) by Chenjie Wang, Michael Levin.

On page 4, Part A one considers 2D (abstarct) Abelian gauge theories with gauge group $G = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{Z}_{N_i} $ and with Abelian braiding statistics. Next is stated the following

> We first discuss the excitation spectrum of these gauge theories. In general, every excitation $\alpha$ in a discrete gauge theory can be labeled by the amount of gauge flux $\phi_{\alpha}$  that it carries. In our case, the gauge flux $\phi_{\alpha}$ can be described by a $K$-component vector  $\phi_{\alpha} = (\phi_{1\alpha}, \phi_{2\alpha}, ...,\phi_{K\alpha})$ where each component $\phi_{i \alpha}$ is a multiple of $2\pi / N_i$ , and is defined modulo $2\pi$. Excitations can be divided into two groups: charge excitations that carry vanishing gauge flux and vortex excitations that carry nonzero gauge flux.

**Question:** Is there any heuristical background/motivation (ie a concrete 'physical' picture) for usage of this terminology to name in abstract gauge theory the excitatations/ quanta which have vanishing gauge flux to be the *'charged excitations'* and those with non vanishing gauge flux to be *'vortex excitations'*? Ie is there a concrete physical picture behind this choice of this terminology one should keep in mind?

For example, what does it mean there that an excitation sort is 'charged', in contrast to those which are 'not charged', the 'vortices'? Precisely, what does it mean for a excitation state/ particle to be 'not charged'?

Theoretically we interpret an excitation sort or 'particle sort' as an irreducible representation of the gauge group and the so called 'charge' could be in abstract terms - cum grano salis - regarded in mathematical terms as the *highest weight* uniquely associated with this representation. So formally, there is a natural way to associate a quantity which we could call a 'charge' at least in this abstract setting to any particle/excitation sort interpreted as the associated irrep of the given gauge group.

But what does then this mean to regard 'vortices' as 'non charged' excitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible explanation of where the terminologies (especially "vortex") come from. One way to get a $Z_N$ gauge theory is to start from a U(1) gauge theory, and couple the U(1) gauge field to a charge-$N$ scalar field $\varphi$. Let us also assume there is a massive charge-1 scalar field $\phi$. Let the charge-$N$ scalar undergoes a Higgs transition.

If one turns off the gauge field, this theory describes a charge-$N$ superfluid. In this superfluid, we can write $\varphi=|\varphi|e^{i\theta}$, where $|\varphi|^2$ (roughly) gives the superfluid density. A vortex is a topological defect around which the phase $\theta$ winds by $2\pi$. This whole configuration can be made charge neutral.

Now we turn back on the gauge field $A$. The coupling between $\varphi$ and $A$ locks $\nabla\theta-NA$ to $0$, so a vortex in $\theta$ carries $2\pi/N$ flux of $A$. This vortex now becomes a finite-energy configuration (it is not in a superfluid without gauge field), carrying $2\pi/N$ gauge flux. This is mostly likely why Wang and Levin called such excitations "vortices".

In the Higgs phase, the massive charge-1 scalar carries the fundamental $Z_N$ gauge charge, which is why they are called "charged excitations".

Comment: just to clarify, when you say that "the charge-N
 scalar undergoes a Higgs transition" you just mean a phase transition in the sense of the standard symmetry breaking Higgs mechanism, right?

Comment: also, could sketch roughly the reason why in setting of 2nd paragraph the considered configuration can be made neutral"?

Comment: @user267839 Yes to your first question.

Comment: @user267839 For the second, one can compute the total charge in the semi-classical limit with a vortex and find that it is 0.