# What means charge-$N$ scalar field $\varphi$?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, lattice-gauge-theory

Let $G = \oplus_{i=1}^N (\mathbb{Z}/N_i)$ be an Abelian group, for sake of simplicity eg a cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/N$ . We consider abstract $G$- gauge theories.

What is in this context the precise definition of a "charge-$N$
scalar field" $\varphi$? I do not understand how to give any meaning to the "charge-$N$" notion.

Motivation: this terminology is used in [this answer.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/773107)
I know there is a well known correspondence between irreducible representations of the gauge group (= particle interpretation) and highest weights, where the later provide mathematical interpretation of "charge". This formally endows canonially any particle (=irrep) carrying $G$-symmetry with a charge.

But I not understand what should the formulation "charge-$N$" mean in this setting.

Comment: Well, in that answer, charge-$N$ refers to the U(1) charge. The U(1) gauge group is broken down to $Z_N$.

Comment: Hint.  Write down the transformation law on $\varphi$ and study it.

Comment: @MengCheng: just to clarify, so the general terminology is: if we dealing with a matter field $\phi$ with $G$-gauge symmetry (=an irred representation of $G$) having degenerated vacuum manifold isomorphic to $G$ and every randomly picked vacuum state retain still an $N$-symmetry, where $N \subset G $ is certain subgroup, then this matter field $\phi$ is what can be called "charge-N", right?

Comment: ...and what about the terminology "charge" here? A guess: do I understand it correctly that the term "charge" refers here to the fact that to any irrep there is a unique weight in mathem sense associated to it due to highest weight correspondence. And this weight assoc to our irrep / matter field $\phi$ is what can be called the "charge". Is this correct?